# Using QQuickView outside of main.cpp

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'am trying to make a new QtQuick 2.0 Gui for an existing C++ project. The old QtGui was managed by a class, so i want to manage the new gui from this class too. So far i opened the gui inside of the main function, but when I move the code to my gui class everything it produces is a small white window. Is there a solution for my problem / where am I wrong?

Here is my code:

```
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QObject>
#include <QQuickItem>

#include "gui.h"
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"

gui::gui(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent)
{
    QQuickView viewer;
    viewer.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("qml/QML-MRGalleyServer/main.qml"));
    viewer.show();
    QQuickItem* object = viewer.rootObject();

    object->setProperty("nextpicture1","Images/widget2.png");
    object->setProperty("nextpicture2","Images/widget7.png");
    object->setProperty("galleyColor","transparent");
}
```

main.cpp:

```
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QtCore>
 #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

 #include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
 #include "gui.h"

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    gui gui;
    gui.show();

    qsrand(QTime(0,0,0).secsTo(QTime::currentTime()));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Also you most likely need to pass _this_ as a parent pointer to the _viewer_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I solved the problem by myself. I had to initiate the QQuickView in the header. gui.h: private: QQuickView* viewer; gui.cpp: viewer = new QQuickView; The white window was caused by gui.show(), so I removed it.